Is there a way to configure credit card details by visiting chrome://settings/payments?
When I try to visit chrome://setttings/payments I am getting error:

Error: page.goto: Target page, context or browser has been closed
Call log:

navigating to "chrome://settings", waiting until "load"


My code:
import { test, chromium } from '@playwright/test'
import { sleep } from './helpers'

test('[INT] Stripe Pay Button', async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
  })
  const context = await browser.newContext()
  const page = await context.newPage()

  await page.goto('chrome://settings/payments')
})

I need to have this to reliably test Stripe PayButton for Google Pay or Apple Pay

No need for writing your own sleep, just use the builtin: import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";. Call with await setTimeout(1000); (or better yet, don't sleep except for temporary debugging).

@Damaon not related to the question you asked. I see [INT] if is it referring to the Test Environment/ Type of Test, better to make use of tags.

@Barney Not better, because I am using Checklyqh.com and not sure if they support playwright tags
